# C++ Boost http client - keep connection alive

Tags: c++, httpclient, boost-asio

I am trying to write some C++ code using Boost:asio that sends data to a server every second. I have taken the example from the Boost docs and made a simple class.

The code below works, however, I am having to create a new instance of the Reporter class within the loop. I would like to have just once class instance and to call the send method. However, if I do that the connection is closed on the second iteration. Is there any way to keep the socket open ? If not can I use the io_service to restart the service in some way. I have looked at the documentation and I am unclear as to how to do this ?

```
#include "Reporter.hpp"
#include <string>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

Reporter::Reporter(std::string host, std::string port) 
    : request_stream(&request), socket(io_service) {

the_host = host;
the_port = port;
tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
tcp::resolver::query query(host, port);
tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
boost::asio::connect(socket, endpoint_iterator);

//request_stream = std::ostream(&request);
}

bool Reporter::send(std::string json) {

try {
    //io_service.reset();
    //io_service.run();
    request_stream << "POST " << "/" << " HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    request_stream << "Host: " << the_host << "\r\n";
    request_stream << "Content-Type: application/json\r\n";
    request_stream << "Content-Length: " << json.length() << "\r\n";    
    request_stream << "Accept: */*\r\n";
    request_stream << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
    request_stream << json;

    // Send the request.
    boost::asio::write(socket, request);

    // Read the response status line. The response streambuf will automatically
    // grow to accommodate the entire line. The growth may be limited by passing
    // a maximum size to the streambuf constructor.
    boost::asio::streambuf response;
    boost::asio::read_until(socket, response, "\r\n");

    // Check that response is OK.
    std::istream response_stream(&response);
    std::string http_version;
    response_stream >> http_version;
    unsigned int status_code;
    response_stream >> status_code;
    std::string status_message;
    std::getline(response_stream, status_message);
    if (!response_stream || http_version.substr(0, 5) != "HTTP/")
    {
    std::cout << "Invalid response\n";
    return 1;
    }
    if (status_code != 200)
    {
    std::cout << "Response returned with status code " << status_code << "\n";
    return 1;
    }

    // Read the response headers, which are terminated by a blank line.
    boost::asio::read_until(socket, response, "\r\n\r\n");

    // Process the response headers.
    std::string header;
    while (std::getline(response_stream, header) && header != "\r")
    std::cout << header << "\n";
    std::cout << "\n";

    // Write whatever content we already have to output.
    if (response.size() > 0)
    std::cout << &response;

    // Read until EOF, writing data to output as we go.
    boost::system::error_code error;
    while (boost::asio::read(socket, response,
        boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1), error))
    std::cout << &response;
    if (error != boost::asio::error::eof)
    throw boost::system::system_error(error);
}
catch (std::exception& e)
{
    std::cout << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
}

  return true;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

int i = 0;
while(i<20000) {
    Reporter wr("localhost", "3000");
    std::string json = "{\"name\":\"avron\"}\r\n\r\n";
    std::cout << "\nSending [" << i << "]\n";
    wr.send(json);
    i++;
    sleep(1);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: To reuse the connection you need to implement HTTP/1.1 keep-alive. Once you switch to HTTP/1.1 you're going to need to support other HTTP/1.1 features (e.g. chunking). Can be done, but it might be much easier to use a library like curl for that.

Comment: curl, which can indeed be used with Asio or Boost Beast